# How to Enable Display Auto detect for thunderbolt 3 (USB C) Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, usb-c, auto-detect

I have a Wacom Cintiq Pro 13 pen display that I use as a secondary monitor. When on, I "project" it as Extended. I even use it as my "primary monitor" to ensure the touch and pen features function on it and not on the 27in screen I normally use as my "real" main display. The problem is that when I turn off the monitor (which is necessary when I slide it out of the way to make space on desk) Windows does not detect that it is off (unless I physically unplug it everytime) and therefore persists to have apps and windows open in the other desktop space where there is no screen of anymore. This is not a problem for displayport cables and maybe even some hdmi situations. However My situation is that this Pen display is linked via DisplayPort over USB-C as Thunderbolt 3 protocol through a usb-c port on my discrete graphics card (motherboard usb c port does not support thunderbolt 3).

Long story short. I want to be able to press the power button on my pen display and automatically have windows "project" as PC Screen Only for my real 27in main monitor.

Relevant Specs:
OS: Windows 10 Home

GPU: Asus RTX 2080 Ti

Motherboard: Asus Maximus XI Gene

Pen Display: Wacom Cintiq Pro 13

Also just in-case: For some reason USB Selective-Suspend does not work with my motherboard and windows 10 combo, I've tried troubleshooting that for many hours for other reasons to no avail. So... not that.

Thank you for any of your time and consideration

Answer (score 0):

Found a workable (although admittedly not the 100% satisfaction I was looking for) solution for anyone with the same problem. It involves some weird connection detection stuff I can't understand yet.

Turn off the pen display with the power button, press the power button again (immeadiately or delayed, doesn't matter) and wait about a second or half of one (I wait for the white touch button LEDs to turn on), and then press the button again to turn the display off before it even fully cuts on. That'll change the display projection to a single "PC Screen Only" mode.

Normally, when I turn off the pen display, nothing happens to Windows. It still acts as if a second display is enabled. HOWEVER! When I go to turn the pen display on, the main display actually flickers off and on again as if the projection setting changed. Why would it do that if it's still in Extended mode, only to ultimately still be in Extended mode? So I just took a chance and interrupted the process, and viola, One monitor on with PC Screen Only projection setting.

Side note, found a fix to my touch/pen input not working properly with pen display not set as primary display (there's built in windows tablet configuration calibration setting just for that).

I'll still be looking for a third party monitor software that supports usb-c monitor detection or something. The couple that I've tried (DisplayFusion & Dual MonitorTools) do not.